# Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to use an `onClick` in a `v-btn` that calls a function that will perform an action, when I click the browser console returns the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name

I'm passing the onclick like this **:**

```
:onClick="viewForm"
```

Using the function call as below, the alert I put to perform tests is generated, but without clicking on `v-btn`, when clicking on `v-btn` the error is generated **:**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

:onClick="viewForm()"
```

Does anyone have an idea what the error could be ? or if some part of my code doesn't make sense.

Every help is welcome :)

Comment: did you tried `@click="viewForm"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind a click event on any element in Vue. You have to use either `@click` or `v-on:click`. You can have a look into this official documentation of [`Event Handling`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#listening-to-events) to understand it in better way.

Hence, change it to `v-on:click="viewForm"` from `:onClick="viewForm"` will work without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

apparently using @click is working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).